# prompt save file download box on click for multiple files

Tags: php, download

php

```
<a href="<?php echo $path_data['wall_path'];?>">
<?php echo $dimensions_data['width'] . "x" . $dimensions_data['height']; ?></a>
```

which outputs

```
<li><a href="wallpapers/2014/04/scape-640x960-640x960.jpg">640x960</a></li>
<li><a href="wallpapers/2014/04/scape-640x1136-640x1136.jpg">640x1136</a></li>
<li><a href="wallpapers/2014/04/scape-720x1280-720x1280.jpg">720x1280</a></li>
<li><a href="wallpapers/2014/04/scape-768x1280-768x1280.jpg">768x1280</a></li>
<li><a href="wallpapers/2014/04/scape-1080x1920-1080x1920.jpg">1080x1920</a></li>
```

Now what I need to do is when the user `clicks` any one of the sizes, I want to prompt a save file dialog box containing the appropriate `size` file. I've read [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php) and [PHP Force File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836492/php-force-file-download), but based on my understanding, these are for single file downloads. Please correct me if not.

Restrictions:
don't want to forward to another page like download.php file when user clicks a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a browser would not show a download dialog for an image, it will display the image instead, what is the desired behaviour. You can then click "Save As ..." and save the image.

What the browser does with a files depends on the mime type which the web server sends for that file. For jpg images it would be

```
image/jpeg
```

If you really want to trick the browser to show a save dialog you need to send a different mime type for that files, like:

```
application/octet-stream
```

This can be done using a download.php file (or whatever) which modifies the header and outputs the file. The existence of such a download.php can be hided from the user using rewritten urls.

If you don't want that, you need to tell the web server that it should send a different mime type for that files. If you run apache for example, you can add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
```

Comment: I'm currently working on local, and using xampp. Sorry, but I haven't tried editing `.htaccess` file. How will I be able to do that? thanks!

Comment: I mean what should be the location of the file. I've checked `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and `AllowOverride All` settings, then created `.htaccess` file in my `htdocs` folder but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is not related to mod rewrite. `AllowOverride FileInfo` would be sufficient in this case, but `All` will work too. I would place the .htaccess in the wallpapers folder. Have you restarted the web server?

Comment: Also empty your browser cache